# How to close AdSense account after upgrading AdMob account?

Tags: google-adsense

I only want AdMob account but had to upgrade from legacy to the new account which has AdSense and AdWords. The Google instructions tells me:

```
"In the “Account information” section, click cancel account."
```

In my account information, there is only Publisher ID, Customer ID, Time zone and Active products which is AdMob. How do I close it?